# How to find the pattern of a signal or main cycle of a signal?

Tags: signal-analysis, python, autocorrelation, time-series, array-signal-processing

I have a dataset where a certain pattern is repeatating in different time interval. The repetation of data pattern can come with slight change. I want first find the pattern (or cycle) and later by checking autocorrelation, fft or similar strategy I filter future data. I have attached a [sample data google drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HfBL_uyCpecCgQm9-XWzaIBRKrxv5gHA/view?usp=sharing) in .npy format.

My present data is not repeating in equivalent interval.

I have also tried with FFT but it also does not work because of uneven interval between cycle.
A solution or direction about how to proceed will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Do you only have one dataset? What I mean is, is this pattern the only pattern you're looking for? Or can other datasets have a different pattern repeating?

Comment: I’m definitely not an expert on the subject but I believe you could try some kind of [Matched-Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matched_filter) approach where you compare the known pattern to the signal and decide on whether the signal is present or not. I believe this is very similar to the [Sum of Absolute Differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_absolute_differences) already suggested in an answer.

Comment: @Jdip I have some other dataset also where pattern can be different for that specific dataset. First I need to detect a pattern (which is unknown to me). Visually I can tell which part is the patteren but algorithomic or coding way still no available solution to me.

Comment: @ZaellixA First I need to detect a pattern (which is yet unknown to me).

Comment: Ah, apologies, I thought the pattern was known in advance. Without the pattern I am not sure how you could tackle the problem… I’m sorry :(...

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question! There are two parts to finding the pattern:

1. Find its length
2. Identify the main pattern of this length

Finding patterns in data series with no a-priori knowledge of the pattern you're looking for is quite difficult. A collection of algorithms that are aimed for this particular task are **Matrix Profile algorithms.**

[**Here**](https://www.cs.ucr.edu/%7Eeamonn/MatrixProfile.html) is the Matrix Profile page where you'll find the purpose, theory and implementations to support your problem. There's also a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/mcyeh/mstamp/tree/master) that seems to have both Python and Matlab implementations.

The algorithm only needs two inputs:

- the data (duh)
- the length $N$ of the pattern you're looking for.

It will then find the sub-sequence of the length specified that is the main pattern in your data.

---

I tried it on a subset of the data you provided, with following result:

1. I first estimated the length of the pattern by running an autocorrelation on the (detrended) data and some peak finding / analysis:
   [image]
2. I then used that to guide the Matrix Profile algorithm:

[image]

Comment: Cool! I might learn something! :-)

Comment: I remembered I had seen this a while back but I went a little deeper into it this time. Cool stuff!

Comment: @Jdip I will try this solution and will comeback with feedback

Comment: I am strugling to get estimated pattern legth using Autocorrelation. 
After running correlation it does not provide me any meaningful insights. 
`autocorr = np.correlate(data, data, mode='full')`

Am I doing something wrong? Suggestion in MATLAB can also be helpful.

Comment: You need to have zero-mean before you correlate: `autocorr = np.correlate(data-np.mean(data) … `

Comment: In general, please, comments such as “it does not provide any meaningful insights” isn’t enough for me to understand what your problem is. In this case I think it’s pretty clear that it’s just a detrending problem, but you need to show what you’re seeing and “why” it doesn’t help.

Comment: @asteroid did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Jdip Unfortunately the solution did not work out for me. Because if there is multiple pattern only one pattern extracted but I need all the possible pattern. Anyway thanks for providing suggestion

Comment: Once you have a pattern, you can find all similar ones in your data and substract them. Then run the whole thing again…maybe… anyways, glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

For the second part, I'd just do the [sum of absolute differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_absolute_differences).

If I pull out this pattern:

[image: Pattern to find]

and run this code:

```py
pattern_to_find = data[117000:121000]
x = np.zeros(len(data))
for k in range(1,(len(data)-len(pattern_to_find)-1)):
        x[k] = np.sum(np.abs(data[k:(4000+k)]-pattern_to_find))
```

then I just get:

[image: SAD similarity measure]

So the idea would be to do a search using the SAD measure something like:

```py
search_lengths = range(3000,5000,100)
search_starts = range(109000,135000,2000)
search_results = np.zeros([len(search_lengths)*len(search_starts),3])
for suspected_length in search_lengths:
    for suspected_start in search_starts:
        suspected_pattern = data[range(suspected_start,suspected_start+suspected_length)]
        x = np.zeros(len(data))
        for k in range(1,(len(data)-len(suspected_pattern)-1)):
            x[k] = np.sum(np.abs(data[k:(suspected_length+k)]-suspected_pattern)) + np.sum(suspected_pattern)
            
        idx = search_lengths.index(suspected_length)*len(search_starts) + search_starts.index(suspected_start)
        search_results[idx,:] = [suspected_length,suspected_start,np.sum(x)/suspected_length]
        print("L:" + str(suspected_length) + " S:" +str(suspected_start) + " Similarity:" + str(search_results[idx]))
```

However, when I do that the best result I get is a "pattern" that is just 1 everywhere:

[image: Found pattern one everywhere.]

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But first part is the most difficult part. How can I find the right length of my pattern ?

Comment: You may have to try different lengths and choose the length that optimizes some criterion, e.g. the magnitude of the peaks of the sum of absolute differences.

Comment: @kasraful Made an attempt, but it needs more thought. :-)

Comment: @MBaz right, I think the SAD needs to be minimized, but my first attempt at that didn't choose an interesting pattern.

Comment: @PeterK. Not surprising :-) Finding non-trivial patterns is probably a non-trivial problem.